# Uniquely identify multiple bluetooth 4.0 devices with same UUID

Tags: iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an iphone application which will communication with multiple bluetooth receivers that all have the same uuid. I am trying to figure out how I can create a mapping to  allow the client to give each device a personalized name that would be persistent across connects/disconnets with the device.  I have done something similiar in bluetooth 3.0 by mapping the name to the mac address of the device, but it doesn't appear the the mac address is available in bluetooth 4.0 of the CBPeripheral. Anyone having any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: How do they have the same UUID? It's generated by the iOS device.

Comment: Ahh.. i was looking at it wrongly. I do not have the receiver to which i will be connecting to so I have not been able to test my code out much. I was thinking that the uuid i was connecting to was the same uuid returned from the peripheral... doh..